# java.lang.NullPointerException when running a testcase via Selenium Android driver

Tags: android, appium, appium-android

I am getting 'Null pointer error' while executing script. But app is getting launched properly on Geny motion but fails to perform further action like clicking on 'Skip user' button.
Below is the code I have written for it

```
public class mainProgram {
    public static AndroidDriver driver;

  @Test
  public void skipUser() { 
  driver.findElement(By.id("com.hp.pregnancy.lite:id/btn_join_later")).click();
  }

  @BeforeMethod
  public void beforeMethod() {
      try {
            File app = new File("D:\\Automation builds\\Testbuild.apk");   
            DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();     
            caps.setCapability("deviceName", "Google Nexus 6P - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 1440x2560");
            caps.setCapability("udid", "192.168.250.101:5555"); //Give Device ID of your mobile phone
            caps.setCapability("platformName", "android");
            caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.1.0");
            caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.hp.pregnancy.lite");
            caps.setCapability("appActivity", "com.hp.pregnancy.lite.onboarding.SplashScreenActivity");
            caps.setCapability("noReset", "true");
            caps.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", "true");
            caps.setCapability("autoDismissAlerts", "true");
        //  caps.setCapability("fullReset",false);
            caps.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath()); 

        Androiddriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), caps);

            System.out.println("Pregnancy+ application launched successfully on Genymotion");
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Step failed - Unable to setup with the predefined Capabilities");
            }
  }

  @AfterMethod
  public void afterMethod() {
      System.out.println("afterMethod");
  }
}
```

Comment: at which line you are getting NullPointerException?

Comment: Please show the console error or error snippet

Comment: ** NullPointerException** error is gone now but new error
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: No command or response codec has been defined. Unable to proceed
is getting displayed...I have updated the code after correction. Could you please help with the latest error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used two `drivers` in your code. One is at the global level which you have declared as `public static` and one you have used and initialised in your `@BeforeMethod`.
So, as the `driver` inside the `@BeforeMethod` is initialised by using `AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), caps);` it is working fine and opening the app. But after that, your code goes to the `@Test` where the driver you are using is the global one and that driver is not initialised and that's why you are getting `NullPointerException`

To solve this problem, please use the same `AndroidDriver driver` in both the `@BeforeMethod` and `@Test`

So, you just need to use `driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), caps);` (which would be initialising the global driver and would be used in your `@Test`) in your `@BeforeMethod` instead of making another `AndroidDriver driver` there, like you were doing by using `AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), caps);`

Comment: Could please mention how it should be done? As I am new to it. I have updated it but not working

Comment: @AressQa  Just use `driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), caps);` after your line of code `caps.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());` and it would work as everything else is fine in your code

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. The error is gone but new error occurred.

Comment: @AressQa What is the error that you are getting now ?

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: No command or response codec has been defined. Unable to proceed

Comment: @AressQa can you post your whole updated code in question itself after making the changes i suggested? Would be easier for me to identify the current issue

Comment: Please find updated code..just removed 'AndroidDriver' as mentioned by you in above comments...

Comment: You can find the resolution of the current exception here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41565615/org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-no-command-or-response-codec-has-been-de This is library/environment path related issue. Please accept my answer by clicking on the "tick" icon corresponding to the answer as it has solved you `NullPointerException` and please revert the question to its initial state for the help of future readers.

Comment: @AressQa happy to help you :)